# Subsetting list-elements based on conditional

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following dataframe

```
mydf<- data.frame(c(1,1,3,4,5,6),
                  c(1,1,3,10,20,30),
                  c(1,10,20,20,15,10))
colnames(mydf)<-c( "ID1","ID2", "ID3")
```

Let's count how many instances of `mydf$ID1` and `mydf$ID2` we have where they appear twice

```
tmp<-plyr::ddply(mydf,c("ID1","ID2"),nrow)
tmp<-tmp[tmp$V1==2,]
```

This has the following output (there's two identical instances)

```
  ID1 ID2 V1
1   1   1  2
```

Now I want to extract the remaining fields, i.e. `ID3`, of these two instances:

```
asd<-mydf[ (mydf$ID1 %in% tmp$ID1) & (mydf$ID1 %in% tmp$ID2), ]
```

This gives me the following

```
  ID1 ID2 ID3
1   1   1   1
2   1   1  10
```

This is exactly as desired and what I wanted, so all good.

---

However, my real data set doesn't only contain 3 vectors like `mydf`, but 300. And each vector is not just 6 elements long, but +50.000

When I run the above method on my data, then I get instances of entries that occur not only 2 times, but also 1, 3, 4 and so on. So that means something is wrong.

Is it because the above method cannot be scaled up to large data? Or is it because the method I outlined above is inherently wrong?

Unfortunately, due to the large size of my data, I cannot post it here.

---

**UPDATE**: Having a list with 3 vectors was just chosen as an example. In reality my data has many vectors, but I still want to group them based on duplicates of two vectors. An example:

```
library(dplyr)


mydf<- data.frame(c(1,  1, 3, 4, 5, 6,0),
                  c(22,22, 3,10,20,30,0),
                  c(2, 10,20,20,15,10,0),
                  c(3, 10,20,20,15,10,0),
                  c(4, 10,20,20,15,10,15),
                  c(5, 99,98,98,97,99,97))
colnames(mydf)<-c( "ID1","ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6")

(mydf %>% group_by(ID5, ID6) %>% filter(n()==2))
```

As desired, this produces

```
    ID1   ID2   ID3   ID4   ID5   ID6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    22    10    10    10    99
2     3     3    20    20    20    98
3     4    10    20    20    20    98
4     5    20    15    15    15    97
5     6    30    10    10    10    99
6     0     0     0     0    15    97
```

Comment: A bug in your code is `(mydf$ID1 %in% tmp$ID2)`, which should be `(mydf$ID2 %in% tmp$ID2)` I think.

Comment: thanks, that is a typo only in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this in easier way with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
    group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% 
    filter(n()==2)
```

If there are more than 2 columns as grouping variables, we can use the `group_by_`

```
mydf %>%
    group_by_(.dots = names(mydf)[1:2]) %>%
    filter(n()==2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot on my data. But do you see an error in my own attempt?

Comment: @BillyJean Did you say that you are getting the expected output with your method in the post?  Beside `ddply` will be slow and the two step process really gets slower

Comment: The method I write above does not give me the expected output when I use it on my own data. But when I use it on clean, "small" data as above it works.

Comment: @BillyJean Not sure why it doesn't work.  This is a group by operation based on the logic you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution is to use `ave` to calculate the duplicate counts, extract the counts, and subset according to which ones are pairwise duplicates.

```
mydf[ave(mydf$ID3, mydf$ID1, mydf$ID2, FUN=length) == 2, ]
  ID1 ID2 ID3
1   1   1   1
2   1   1  10
```

To extend the grouping to many variables, you can replace the explicit listing of ID1 and ID2 with the output of `Reduce` and `interaction` like this:

```
mydf[ave(mydf$ID3, Reduce(interaction, mydf[-3]), FUN=length) == 2, ]
  ID1 ID2 ID3
1   1   1   1
2   1   1  10
```

Here, `Reduce(interaction, mydf[-3])` constructs a factor variable that is the interaction of ID1 and ID2. This will happily take as many vectors as you provide.

Comment: Thanks. How can this be generalized to a list with `m` vectors and not just 3?

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was that I still want to calculate the duplicate counts of ID1 and ID2, but now all other rows that I want to extract are ID3, ID4, ID5, etc. Sorry if I was being unclear in my previous comment.

Comment: The original should work for two ID vectors and unlimited other vectors. the `df[` at the beginning says subset df according to the rules inside `[  ]`. Using a logical vector applies the subsetting to all the vectors in df. If there is an additional complication not covered in your example. Please consider asking a new question. If it is only something small, then maybe post a second example.

Comment: @BillyJean Have you tried my code on your second example? I get the same result as your desired result except that the rownames differ.